# linux batch jobs in parallel

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, background-process, batch-processing

I have seven licenses of a particular software. Therefore, I want to start 7 jobs simultaneously. I can do that using '&'. Now, 'wait' command waits till the end of all of those 7 processes to be finished to spawn the next 7. Now, I would like to write the shell script where after I start the first seven, as and when a job gets completed I would like to start another. This is because some of those 7 jobs might take very long while some others get over really quickly. I don't want to waste time waiting for all of them to finish. Is there a way to do this in linux? Could you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check how many are currently running and start more if you have less than 7:

```
while true; do
    if [ "`ps ax -o comm | grep process-name | wc -l`" -lt 7 ]; then
        process-name &
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: `ps auxw | grep process-name | wc -l` will show 8 when here is 7 processes started

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use ps auxw but a command that monitors how many licenses are currently in use (irrespective of user id because they are shared network licenses). I liked the idea of using 'if' to check it and sleep for a few seconds. That helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

[GNU `parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is the way to go. It is designed for launching multiples instances of a same command, each with a different argument retrieved either from `stdin` or an external file.

Let's say your licensed script is called `myScript`, each instance having the same options `--arg1 --arg2` and taking a variable parameter `--argVariable` for each instance spawned, those parameters being stored in file `myParameters` :

```
cat myParameters | parallel -halt 1 --jobs 7 ./myScript --arg1 --argVariable {} --arg2
```

Explanations :

- `-halt 1` tells `parallel` to halt all jobs if one fails
- `--jobs 7` will launch 7 instances of `myScript`

On a debian-based linux system, you can install `parallel` using :

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

As a bonus, if your licenses allow it, you can even tell `parallel` to launch these 7 instances amongst multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

Write two scripts. One which restarts a job everytime it is finished and one that starts 7 times the first script.

Like:

```
script1:

./script2 job1
...
./script2 job7
```

and

```
script2:

while(...)
  ./jobX
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly good solution using [make](/questions/tagged/make), which is a part of the standard distributions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565353/have-5-scripts-running-at-any-given-time/17566149#17566149)