# Have 5 scripts running at any given time

Tags: linux, bash, centos, centos6

I have a bash script (running under CentOS 6.4) that launches 90 **different** PHP scripts, ie.

```
#!/bin/bash

php path1/some_job_1.php&
php path2/some_job_2.php&
php path3/some_job_3.php&
php path4/some_job_4.php&
php path5/some_job_5.php

php path6/some_job_6.php&
php path7/some_job_7.php&
php path8/some_job_8.php&
php path9/some_job_9.php&
php path10/some_job_10.php
...

exit 0
```

In order to avoid overloading my server, I use the ampersand `&`, it works, but **my goal is to always have 5 scripts running at the same time**

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux batch jobs in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536231/linux-batch-jobs-in-parallel)

Comment: @DavidJashi: The keyword is **different PHP scripts**, I'm studying parallel, thanks!

Comment: `parallel` does not really care, whether it's PHP or bash or whatever. Behavior and solution is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is popped several times, but I could not find a proper answer for it. I think now I found a good solution!

Unfortunately `parallel` is not the part of the standard distributions, but [make](/questions/tagged/make) is. It has a switch `-j` to do makes parallel.

[man make(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary)]: ([more info on make's parallel execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel))

> ```
>   -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
>         Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If
>         there  is  more than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If
>         the -j option is given without an argument, make  will  not  limit
>         the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.
> ```

So with a proper `Makefile` the problem could be solved.

```
.PHONY: all $(PHP_DEST)

# Create an array of targets in the form of PHP1 PHP2 ... PHP90
PHP_DEST := $(addprefix PHP, $(shell seq 1 1 90))

# Default target
all: $(PHP_DEST)

# Run the proper script for each target
$(PHP_DEST):
        N=$(subst PHP,,$@); php path$N/some_job_$N.php
```

It creates 90 of `PHP#` targets each calls `php path#/some_job_#.php`. If You run `make -j 5` then it will run 5 instance of php parallel. If one finishes it starts the next.

I renamed the `Makefile` to `parallel.mak`, I run `chmod 700 parallel.mak` and I added `#!/usr/bin/make -f` to the first line. Now it can be called as `./parallel.mak -j 5`.

Or even You can use the more sophisticated `-l` switch:

> ```
>   -l [load], --load-average[=load]
>         Specifies  that  no new jobs (commands) should be started if there
>         are others jobs running and the load average is at least  load  (a
>         floating-point number).  With no argument, removes a previous load
>         limit.
> ```

In this case [make](/questions/tagged/make) will decide how many jobs can be launched depending on the system's load.

I tested it with `./parallel.mak -j -l 1.0` and run nicely. It started 4 programs in parallel at first contrary `-j` without args means run as many process parallel as it can.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detailed answer trueY! The paths mentioned in my question are actually just examples, but I see your point, I'll try my best to adapt it, thanks again for your help man!

Comment: @TheDude: I'm happy that I could help you and I find a proper solution for this problem. I met this problem many times before and I could make only half-hearted solutions.

Comment: @TheDude: I did a minor modification in the receipt of temp targets to avoid multiple `subst`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron` and schedule them at the same time.
Or use [parallel](http://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel).